# iPhone task switcher image is black

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I've inherited a code base and just noticed that when I close the app (hit home button) and then attempt to switch to that app using the task switcher (double tap home button) my application appears in the task switcher with a completely black image instead of the expected screenshot of the last page I was viewing.

Has this happened to anyone else?  Any thoughts as to what might be causing it?  As I said I inherited this code base so I'm as a loss as to what might have caused this.

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) figured out what was happening below in the accepted answer, but I thought I'd add some logs here incase anyone else runs into this:

```
// Logs showing a correct shutdown
Sep 26 16:48:14 iPod-touch iap2d[2096] <Warning>: process HTTPLeakTester is now running in the background
Sep 26 16:48:15 iPod-touch iap2d[2096] <Warning>: process HTTPLeakTester is now suspending

// Logs Showing my killed app's shutdown
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch iap2d[2096] <Warning>: process ***** is now running in the background
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch SpringBoard[42] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch SpringBoard[42] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:*****[0x5d54]' exited voluntarily.
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch assertiond[56] <Error>: assertion failed: 12A365: assertiond + 62335 [032107D4-DB2B-36DD-AC98-6060D8C62F73]: 0x3
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch assertiond[56] <Warning>: pid_suspend failed for <BKNewProcess: 0x16614640; *****; pid: 2386>: Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch Unknown[56] <Error>: 
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch assertiond[56] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16614640; *****; pid: 2386> to 2, priority: No such process
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch assertiond[56] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16614640; *****; pid: 2386> to 4096, priority: No such process
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch assertiond[56] <Error>: assertion failed: 12A365: assertiond + 62335 [032107D4-DB2B-36DD-AC98-6060D8C62F73]: 0x3
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch UserEventAgent[17] <Warning>: id=***** pid=2386, state=0
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch iap2d[2096] <Warning>: process ***** is now switching to other state
Sep 26 16:47:19 iPod-touch iap2d[2096] <Warning>: process ***** is now terminated
```

Comment: Search for `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I did that already after google searching this issue.  It's not in this code base.

Comment: Can you track down what else might be happening in application `willResignActive` and `didEnterBackground`? (Search on those phrases.)

Comment: Neither is implemented.  If it were that simple I'd never have needed to ask, unfortunately.

Comment: I was afraid that's just what you'd say. :( I have a vague memory of my own app doing this and I'm trying to reconstruct why. Has the app actually been recompiled for the latest system? My vague memory is that I had this problem until then; e.g. an iOS 6 app running on iOS 7 could act like this.

Comment: Ooooh oooooh I've just had a great idea. See my answer below.

Comment: Matt in answer to your system question, this app was iOS7 when I got it, and had the problem, and I've updated it since to iOS8 and still has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the app is mismanaging memory (or possibly trying to do something else wrong when it is backgrounded, such as using a lot of CPU for too long). You inherited it, after all, so you don't know and it isn't your fault. The result is that when we go into the background, the watchdog process sees that the app is behaving badly and kills it summarily.

You can confirm this if you go into the background with the app switcher, switch to the black snapshot, and launch, and if the app then launches from scratch. This proves that it was terminated in the background.

If that guess is right, then the problem should go away when the app is a better citizen.

Comment: Oooo, good guess.  The app does get completely killed.  They built it with a ton of timers that are flooding the network with requests (I'm working on cleaning this up now) and I could see the OS killing that on exit.